# Bootstrap 3: How to close popup using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my code there is two popup windows. first for login and second for reset password.
The link to second popup is inside of login popup. I want to automatically close login popup when i click link forgot password.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".loginform">Login</a>
<!- Login Popup start-->

<div id="login" class="modal fade loginform" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    ....
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"><span style="font-size:12px;display:block;">Remember me</span>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".forgotpassword" href="#" style="float:left;font-size:14px;">Forgot Password</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
</div>


<!- popuplogin end-->
<!- Popup forgot password start-->

<div id="forgot" class="modal fade forgotpassword" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    .......
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
</div>


<!- popup end-->
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mridulpv/V3Wws/4/)

Comment: You really need to fix the indentaion.

Comment: Do you really think a modal a-top of another modal is good UX design? I don't.

Comment: I want close 1st model when click into the link of second. I don't know more about UX design. But I try to do it..

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Bootstrap 2? Because Bootstrap 3 doesn't support overlapping modals by default. Also, I wonder if it isn't more convenient in the first place to just swap content in one modal instead of closing and opening two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

keep an id for forget password link and on click do `$('#login').modal('hide');`

```
$("#forgotPass").click(function(){
       $('#login').modal('hide');
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/2xWmc/)**

Answer (score 7):

In this documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Showing:
`$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Hiding:
`$('#myModal').modal('hide');`

Comment: @mridul Didn't I answered first?